# TeamCity Vs BuildForge

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, buildforge

We are currently using TeamCity and planning to move on to BuildForge because of organizational needs/constraints. I want to do a feature comparison on TeamCity and BuildForge. Could anyone please help me on this. As I could find comparison of BuildForge with other CI tools such as Hudson, CruiseControl only.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the other comparisons as a baseline (especially the Hudson one which will be quite close), and basically create a matrix of features you care about, and see which tools do what. You may ask IBM for their break-down.

A great list of features for CI tools in general (with data on TC) is the CI comparison matrix: 
[CI Feature Matrix](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CC/CI+Feature+Matrix) and [Comparison of Continuous Integration Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Continuous_Integration_Software).

At Urbancode, our AnthillPro product competes pretty directly against Build Forge, our take on a feature matrix is in a white-paper ["Continuous Integration and Build Management Server Evaluation Guide"](http://www.urbancode.com/html/resources/white-papers/Continuous_Integration_and_Build_Management_Server_Evaluation_Guide/) (registration required).

Basically, I think you'll find that BF is capable of handling a larger environment (scalability, security, scalability type strengths) while TC is more of pure, team level CI server (wider range of integrations, and test trending type activities).

Comment: Thanks, the whitepaper gave me a good insight to the difference between a CI and BM tool and their purpose.

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've used BuildForge, actually I used it together with ClearCase, ClearQuest, for more than a decade and today I still have to use it at one client. My experience is: forget about IBM, come to the new age. It's Git, JIRA, Jenkins, artifactory's world. I've seen TeamCity but didn't use a lot. This is the only build tool I heard better than Jenkins somehow.

Forget about BuildForge, it's old, slow, hard to use. Comparing to tools like Jenkins has endless plugins, BF is just a shell provides nothing so you will have to write everything yourself, and in Perl. How many young developers can't write in Perl, comparing to Groovy? Comparing BF to Jenkins is like comparing C language to Java.

Give an example on what I am doing these days: move a BF instance to another server. For Jenkins, it's just a copy of a directory. In BF, you need to spend a week to figure out.